# My if and else statements in verilog are not giving expected results

Tags: if-statement, verilog

I am trying a simple code to compare an input to some value(threshold) and tried using the if and else condition statements to assign a variable to either 0 or 1 depending of the variable crossing the threshold or not. But, in this case I am always getting same single value for different inputs. I am new to verilog and trying to write an algorithm for a different application, in which this is my first step. Thanks in advance.

```
module makebig(a,z);
input signed [15:0]  a;
output reg z;
initial
begin
if (a<16'b0000000000000000) begin
 z<=1;
end
else  begin
 z<=0;
end

end
endmodule
```

Now the test bench of it.

```
module makebig_tb();

reg  signed [15:0] a;

wire z;

makebig uut(.a(a),.z(z));
initial
begin
a=16'b0100000000000000;
#5 a=16'b000000000000101;
#5 a=-2;
end
initial
begin
$monitor("a=%b,z=%b",a,z);
end
end module
```

I don't understand why it is not working. The output for this is something like this...

```text
a=0100000000000000,z=0;
a=0000000000000101,z=0;
a=1111111111111110,z=0;
```

Comment: Not my area,  but.... Are you sure the constant in `if` is signed? May be the comparison is evaluated in unsigned numbers despite `input signed` declaration....

Comment: Yes, in the assignment of the variable a, I have mentioned 'signed'. I even tried taking the half of 2^16 as the threshold but, still not the expected results.

Comment: Your `if` statement only gets executed once at time 0.

Comment: @dave_59 I didn't understand. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Does this: [**Why is this verilog relational statement returning true?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340093/) answer your question?

Comment: I've seen you used `signed` to declare `a`, but I did not ask about `a` but rather about _the constant_ you compare `a` to. In other words, are you sure `16'b0000000000000000` is signed? The answers at the question I link in the comment above suggest it should be unsigned, and the whole comparison is done as unsigned. And _none_ unsigned value is less than zero, hence your constant output of `z` equal `0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this verilog relational statement returning true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340093/why-is-this-verilog-relational-statement-returning-true)

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors here, and both of them have been pointed out in the comments:

1. You are only running the comparison once (`initial begin`). Replace this with `always @(*) begin` to run it each time one of the inputs changes
2. A comparison with an unsigned constant will result in the whole comparison being unsigned. Replace `16'b0000000000000000` with `$signed(16'b0000000000000000)`

This produces the expected output

```
a=0100000000000000,z=0;
a=0000000000000101,z=0;
a=1111111111111110,z=1;
```